Smoke node tree and path help needed
I've been trying to create an airflow simulation through a tube system in Blender. I have tried for weeks using various solutions such as smoke simulations with physics and force fields to a variety of node experiments. I've pulled ideas from Youtube videos and the depths of the internet but can't quite get it right.
I've also tried this method which is almost exactly what I'm looking for, but still have the same issue of sizing down the smoke and not upsizing the tubes (which is why I leaned into a node base to not have to use a domain). Plus I can't control the speed of the flow.
https://cgcookie.com/community/7011-smoke-simulation-in-blender
I created a smoke node that I am happy with, but I'm having an issue placing it inside a mesh. It follows the path of a curve currently, that I have placed inside the pipe mesh. The Node system uses points for the smoke and I'm stuck on how to scale it down to fit in the tubing. I've also tried points >volume to volume>mesh configurations with no luck.
I'm open to any ideas or simpler solutions anyone has as my goal is to show a type of airflow from tank to tank through this tubing. I've include a screen shots of the tubing, node setup, and other information.
Images:

Is of my pipe mesh I'm wanting smoke to flow through.
Is the node smoke I'm happy with but cannot scale down to fit in pipe.
Node smoke tree for reference
Another solution I experimented with but when applied to my pipe mesh, it disappears in viewport. Plus I cannot locate the same node in 4.2

As always, appreciate all help from this community.



Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"
